# Simple Function in R error

Tags: r

I'm following an instruction video in a course I have to take. 
The task is to write a simple function in R and load it to the console.
The instructions are to write the code as follows:

```
myfunction <- function() (  
    x <- rnorm(100)  
    mean(x)   
)
```

When I attempt to copy this to the console it gives the following error:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"x <- rnorm(100)
mean"
```

Then when I type `myfunction` into the console as instructed I get this:

```
function() 
x <- rnorm (100)
```

I could find a way around this if it were not a course where I obviously have to follow this instructions given. But since it is and I am entirely new to R I hope that someone will help me identify the error here so i can get this to work properly.
I'm using windows 10 and R 3.5
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you are using `(` instead of `{` to define the function body. This should resolve the error -

```
myfunction <- function() {  
    x <- rnorm(100)  
    mean(x)   
}
```

Comment: OMG thank you. I guess video quality is more important than I anticipated. I feel like I should have know this from using basics of other languages though :/